# Python 3.6 tuple strange behavior?

Tags: python

Can somebody explain why does Python 3.6 behaves so strange in this piece of code?

```
a = (1, 2, [5, 6])
a[2]+=[7, 8]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>>print(a)
(1, 2, [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: What is the result, and what did you expect?

Comment: I want to point out this is way more subtle than it seems. += usually extends in place

Comment: @JonasWolff Yea but the list inside can be. And it does update

Comment: Even if you get an exception on `a[2]+=[7, 8]` the list is updated. I guess the question is based on this fact.

Comment: One might expect is that replacing `a[2]+=[7, 8]` by  `a[2].extend([7,8])` would have the same behaviour. It does, but no error message.